# How to use WeightedCluster::wcKMedoids to provide clustering for heatmap or heatmap.2 in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap

TL;DR: How to use the `WeightedCluster` library (the `wcKMedoids()` method in particular) as input to `heatmap`, `heatmap.2` or similar, to provide it with clustering info?

---

We are creating a heatmap from some binary data (yes/no values, represented as ones and zeros) in R, and need to adjust the weights of some of the rows for the column based clustering.

(they are generated from multi-choice categories into multiple binary yes/no-valued rows, and thus are getting over-represented).

I found the [WeightedCluster](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WeightedCluster/index.html) library, which can do clustering with weights.

Now the question is how to use this library (the `wcKMedoids()` method in particular) as input to `heatmap`, `heatmap.2` or similar?

I have tried the following code, which results in the error message below:

```
library(gplots)
library(WeightedCluster)

dataset <- "
F,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8
A,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1
B,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1
C,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
D,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0
E,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0
F,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
G,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1
H,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
I,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
J,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
K,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
L,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1
M,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
N,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1"
fakefile <- textConnection(dataset)

d <- read.csv(fakefile, header=T, row.names = 1)

weights <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

distf <- function(x) dist(x, method="binary")
wclustf <- function(x) wcKMedoids(distf(x), 
                                 k=8, 
                                 weights=weights, 
                                 npass = 1, 
                                 initialclust=NULL, 
                                 method="PAMonce", 
                                 cluster.only = FALSE, 
                                 debuglevel=0)

cluster_colors <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))(256);
heatmap(as.matrix(d), 
        col=cluster_colors,
        distfun = distf,
        hclustfun = wclustf,
        keep.dendro = F,
        margins=c(10,16),
        scale="none")
```

But running it gives:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.dendrogram") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.dendrogram' applied to an object of class "c('kmedoids', 'list')"
```

Apparently, `wcKMedoids` is not a drop-in replacement for R's `hclust`, but does anyone have some pointers on how to work around that?

**UPDATE:** The tiny progress I have made so far indicates that I should implement a method `as.dendrogram.kmedoids`, that produces a similar output as `hclust(dist(x))`. (Its output can be inspected in detail with `dput`: `dput(hclust(dist(x)))`). Ideas and pointers much welcome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: @gung Sorry about this (bit new to R, and how to do things), made the code example fully self-contained and reproducible now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done. K-Medoid clustering is a partioning method, not a hierarchical one. Dendogram is only meaningful for hierarchical clustering algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make do with a simpler solution, this just multiply the weights into the original matrix, giving them larger weights this way. I'm not 100% sure that this is the statistically correct way to do this, but depending on what you want to achieve it might do the job.

```
# Create the dataset
dataset <- matrix(
  dimnames = list(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 14 )], c("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5","T6","T7","T8")),
  data = c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
           1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,
           1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,
           0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,
           0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,
           1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,
           1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,
           1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,
           0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1),
  ncol=8,
  nrow=14)

# Assign weights to the different columns
col.weights <- c(2,3,1,1,1,1,1,1)

# Transform the original matrix with the weights
# you want to assign to each column.
create.weights.matrix <- function(weights, rows) {
  sapply(weights, function(x){rep(x, rows)})
}
weights.matrix <- create.weights.matrix(col.weights, nrow(dataset))
d.weighted <- weights.matrix * dataset

# Create the plot
cluster_colors <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))(256);
heatmap(as.matrix(d.weighted), 
        col=cluster_colors,
        keep.dendro = F,
        margins=c(10,16),
        scale="none")
```

This will give you something like this as a result:

[image: heatmap with weights]